# Migrate P4 to Git - Could not preserve history

Tags: git, perforce

I am trying to move project from P4 to Git.  I was told that it is not possible to migrate the history info from P4 to Git, is this correct?  Is there anyway to migrate the history info?

Thanks

Comment: This is answered in [Git - Migrating to Git - Perforce](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git#Perforce) better than in any answer I could write here.

Comment: its clear you are clueless but whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Git Fusion, which is a bridge between Perforce and Git.

It works in both directions, so Git user's can continue using it, while submitting to Perforce.

More information is available here:

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r16.1/manuals/git-fusion/

Comment: Would Fusion work without admin installing on server-side?